# Is this an error? Will it affect my code in any way?

Tags: python, numpy

In my terminal, this is the only thing that pops up. Does it mean my code won't run, and how can I fix it? Also will my code run if this is there?

```
FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
```

Comment: It is a warning not an error.. but you should always post your code so we can know what is going on

Comment: It looks like it is just a warning, so it won't stop your script from running so long as you don't upgrade the package that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it is a warning.

It means basically what it says, that the feature you are using is deprecated in newer versions of numpy and tells you how to run the equivalent command in newer versions.

There isn't much information that I could find on documentation of FutureWarnings other than:

[FutureWarnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FutureWarning)

but for now your code will run.

you can also suppress the warning if you want using this:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action = "ignore", category = FutureWarning)
```

this will not change how your code executes, just won't show the warning.